# How can I control de output in bash using dig?

Tags: regex, bash, dig

I using the following bash to get DNS records of multiples domains inside domains.txt

```
#!/bin/bash
for domain in $(cat domains.txt); do dig @8.8.8.8 $domain ANY +multiline +noall +answer +nocmd; done
```

Current dig output is:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @8.8.8.8 aeapi.bluetail.salesforce.com ANY +multiline +noall +answer +nocmd
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
site.com. 59 IN A 0.0.0.1
site.com. 59 IN A 0.0.0.0
```

And I like get the output on the following format:

```
site.com,0.0.0.1
site2.com,0.0.0.2
site3.com,0.0.0.4
```

how can I do this? help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display only the `IN A` lines in comma-separated format:

```
for domain in $(cat domains.txt); do dig @8.8.8.8 $domain ANY +multiline +noall +answer +nocmd; done | awk '/IN A ([[:digit:]]+\.){3}/{gsub(/\.$/,"",$1); print $1","$NF}'
```

Or, for those who like their commands spread over multiple lines:

```
for domain in $(cat domains.txt)
do
   dig @8.8.8.8 $domain ANY +multiline +noall +answer +nocmd
done | awk '/IN A ([[:digit:]]+\.){3}/{gsub(/\.$/,"",$1); print $1","$NF}'
```

#### How it works

1. `/IN A ([[:digit:]]+\.){3}/{...}`

   This selects lines that look like `IN A` followed by an IP address.  (Actually, we only check for three sets of digits followed by a period but, here, that is good enough.)  For those and only those lines, the commands inside curly braces are executed.
2. `gsub(/\.$/,"",$1)`

   For the selected lines, we remove the period from the end of the first field.
3. `print $1","$NF`

   For the selected lines, we print the first field, a comma, and the last field,

#### Aside

The command `for domain in $(cat domains.txt)` has some issues.  In particular, the contents of `domains.txt` will be subjected to *word-splitting* and *pathname expansion* and that may cause unexpected behavior.  Depending on the format of `domains.txt`, there will be much better ways of reading the contents of this file.

#### Adding double-quotes to the output

```
for domain in $(cat domains.txt); do dig @8.8.8.8 $domain ANY +multiline +noall +answer +nocmd; done | awk '/IN A ([[:digit:]]+\.){3}/{gsub(/\.$/,"",$1); printf "\"%s\",\"%s\"\n",$1,$NF}'
```

Comment: Thanks John1024. Now the output is: "domain.com. 21599 IN A 127.0.0.1" and I like to change the output to: "domain.com,127.0.0.1" (separated with a comma)

Comment: @pancho OK.  See update for a way to just print the IP lines with comma-separated format.

Comment: Hello again. How can I add " to the output for example: "3d.ebay.com","66.211.188.45" with print "$1"",""$NF"  ??

Comment: @pancho OK.  I added to the end of the answer an example that puts double-quotes around the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the `dig` output into any other program. You may want to use sed, I'm more used to grep. `grep -v -e "<regex>"` will delete any line which matches the regular expression `<regex>`.

Let's explain the regular expression `"^$\|^;"` : `^$` stands for empty line, `^;` stands for a line that start with `;`, `|` means the logical operator OR, and `\` escapes the `|` character (it tells grep that this is an operator and not a regular character).

So the command you may want would be like this :

```
$ dig stackoverflow.com | grep -v -e "^$\|^;"

stackoverflow.com.      1003    IN      A       151.101.1.69
stackoverflow.com.      1003    IN      A       151.101.193.69
stackoverflow.com.      1003    IN      A       151.101.129.69
```

Edit : if you want to get rid of the `1003   IN   A` you can pipe into the sed command :

`sed "s/.\s*[0-9]*\s*IN\s*A\s*/, /"`.

The format is `s` (which stands for substitute) `/` matching regexp `/` what you want `/`

Comment: minor nit: the `grep -v` command matches any line which *does not* match the regex